# Shutter very slow and laggy?

Tags: performance, shutter

Shutter is very slow and laggy and I'm not sure why. I've tried to change settings to "Do not save file automatically" and "Do not copy anything to clipboard" but it's still incredibly slow. I have it bound to my `Print Screen` button and when I hit it my computer will seize up for 10 to 45 seconds. I can still move my mouse, but it's slow and I can't perform any actions with keyboard or clicks.

I have 6gb RAM with trim and a very small swap. 2 monitors, which I'm sure doesn't help. But I don't think this should be happening regardless.

Comment: is this question still open after these years? can you check for memory status? using "free", "top", and/or "htop" to see... some times lack of enough memory and running on SWAP may reduce many process...

Comment: apparently it's no longer open, seeing that you ask about that more than 1 year ago.  Is there not an "autoclose feature" ?  (Like no activity, and no answer, and no comments ==> Close)